# Has George Lucas ever confirmed Palpatine was anti-woman and anti-alien?

Tags: star-wars

I think I remember the Star Wars Expanded Universe saying Palpatine hated women and aliens. I know Pellaeon mentions it in The Hand of Thrawn at least. I guess writers based this on no girls or aliens on Star Destroyers in the original trilogy. But in the prequels Palpatine is chummy with loads of aliens (Darth Maul, the blue guy in Episode 1, the Viceroy) and girls, well, girl (Padme) so I'm wondering whether GL ever spoke up about it.

Comment: I would out that the Viceroy (and I believe Darth Maul) were both betrayed by Palpatine... wasn't he already corrupting Dooku when Maul was sent to fight two Jedi?

Comment: This question was asked from an out-of-universe viewpoint, while the other questions about Palpatine come at it from in-universe. The other questions ask about Palpatine the character, using the totality of his "history" of all canon elements, especially including the expanded universe. This question is asking about the intention of George Lucas himself and whether he had given a viewpoint about Palpatine and his bias, which aren't evident in the films themselves, of which George Lucas has repeatedly said show his definitive version of Star Wars.

Comment: "I don't read that stuff. I haven't read any of the novels. I don't know anything about that world. That's a different world than my world....When I said [other people] could make their own Star Wars stories, we decided that, like Star Trek, we would have two universes: My universe and then this other one. They try to make their universe as consistent with mine as possible, but obviously they get enthusiastic and want to go off in other directions." - George Lucas, from an interview in Starlog #337

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there has never been any confirmation from George Lucas regarding Palpatine's xenophobia or chauvinism. In fact, the portrayals of Palpatine in the the prequel trilogy have encouraged a ret-conning of Palpatine as not personally prejudiced, but following policies set by his advisors. The use of a clone army also encourages a pro-human outlook.

The idea of Palpatine as xenophobic was developed primarily by Timothy Zahn in *Dark Force Rising* and *Mist Encounter*, with other *EU* authors adopting it. Kevin J. Anderson added the chauvinism in *Jedi Search*. This was done to explain the lack of aliens or women in Imperial forces in the films, which was due to budgetary and technological limitations. With those limitations gone, Lucas expanded on alien - though not greatly on female - roles in the prequel trilogy, as well as *The Clone Wars*.

This is not to say that there is no evidence that Palpatine was anti-alien. In the novelisation of *Revenge of the Sith* for example - while written by Matt Stover, Lucas had final say over the novelisation's contents - Count Dooku is revealed as being very speciesist, with a plan to recreate the Republic as an "Empire of Man." Stover may have been making an homage to Zahn's 'Dominion of Man' in the *Cobra* series with that quote. How many of his apprentice's views Palpatine shared is debatable, but the evidence that he was at least mildly xenophobic is there.

Comment: In the novel *Plagueis*, it states that Palpatine purposely organized the Separatists to be composed of powerful organizations led by non-humans so that he could rid them of their power.

Comment: @jliv902: Interesting. I haven't read that novel yet (and given the current state of the *EU* hadn't planned to, to be honest). Odd then that he would have several non-humans as close aides.